# How to disable other buttons till the function call is complete after clicking on one in react render()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My function call takes some time to produce display, if any other button is clicked the result is overlapped and that is not desired. I need to disable all toggle buttons until one function call is complete, including reset button. Also, please can anyone add how do I display my function runtime on render screen. I'm getting the time in console window, I need to display it on screen below my div.

```
return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => this.resetfunc()}>Reset</button>
                <button onClick={() => this.func1()}>Function 1</button>
                <button onClick={() => {const start = performance.now();
                                        this.func2();
                                        const end = performance.now();
                                        console.log(end-start);}}>Function 2</button>
                <button onClick={() => this.func3()}>Function 3</button>
            </div>
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

React always renders your current state (in a broad sense). So, if you want something to change, you have to change your state.

For example, you can have "working" state. In this state your buttons would be disabled (generally bad idea from UX point of view). And then, in "not_working" state all buttons would be enabled. Your goal is to switch your state when needed.

And for time your function worked - state again. If you want render something, you have to either hardcode it (like "Function 2" text), or put into state (in a broad sense).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a state for tracking if data is processing. The same can be used after the data is set.

```js
const [processing, setProcessing] = useState(false)
```

When clicking a button,

```html
<button disabled={this.processing} onClick={() => (this.setProcessing(true);this.resetfunc())}>Reset</button>
```

Also don't forget to reset it in your function call (Or keep it hanging if you want the buttons permanently disabled)

```js
const resetfunc = () => {
  // Do something cool here
  this.setProcessing(false)
}
```